# Replacing an example question on 2-minute Tour

Tags: discussion, help-center

As you all know, our Help Center, especially our 2-minute tour will be a general guidance to all future users.

[Koreean SE's 2-minute Tour](https://korean.stackexchange.com/tour) shows an example question, [What is a polite term of address to use for a friend's mother?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-is-the-polite-name-to-use-for-a-friends-mother).

I don't think this is a good example because it doesn't show any self-research efforts and reads more like a question for a question's sake. I mean, how many times do you meet your friend's mother and call her, especially when you are a learner?

Any thought or suggestions?

**Edit**: And the second answer suggesting '아주머니' is wrong.

Comment: The question is a paraphrasing of [one of our definition questions] (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74396#74396), asked in the rush of excitement at the start of the beta. It's true that if the asker of the original definition question (me!) had asked it here, they would have fleshed it out a bit more. It is a genuine question though - when you're a Korean learner *living in Korea*, such situations and problems occur regularly!

Comment: @topomorto Well, I am not denying the legitimacy of the question. The issue is (1) The second answer is not right. I have never called any of my friend's mother "아주머니". It sounds very rude. (2) Now we have a better question that has some research and context. I don't think there is any harm trying to find a better question. (3) The question might mislead new users into believing that they can ask any question like that, i.e. "What's this and what's that?". I don't think the question format is desirable on Korean SE.

Comment: 1) I don't have the knowledge to comment 2) I agree.3) I agree. The original definition phrasing of this question might be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This question has some points in its favour:

- It's short, and therefore fits within the small 'window' in the tour page
- It has a number of answers, most of which are also quite short
- it is on-topic

If we can't find an obvious alternative, we could edit '[What is a polite term of address to use for a friend's mother?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-is-the-polite-name-to-use-for-a-friends-mother)' slightly to be a better exemplar.

Comment: I'm still interested what alternatives people come up with!

Comment: I have left two comments to MujjinGun. I think at least  it's better to get rid of the answer from the tour page.

Answer (score 1):

After browsing the Questions page sorted by vote count, I found this quite suitable:
[How can I ask someone to repeat a statement in Korean?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-ask-someone-to-repeat-a-statement-in-korean)

- rather concise question as well as answers, simplicity is always good for basic example
- although 1/3 of the question body is probably invisible on the Tour page, the question's title pretty much says it all
- has a diverse bunch of correct answers
- IMHO the topic is virtually at the very core of our site's scope (compare questions like etymology, still well on-topic but not quite the most important kind of topic, though I do like etymology very much)